# Swift3, How to call ClassA class function in ClassB init ()

Tags: swift

I have a web-service which returns a generic JSON structure in following format

`{
"status" : "failure",
"message": "Unauthorized",
"payload" : []//could be object array depending on service end-point
}`

In above, "payload" can have any Object Array.In my case lets say it will return either [Book] or [Page] depending what service i have called.

Now i have created three models Result , Book , Page as follow

```
class Book {

    public var id : Int = 0
    public var bookName : String = ""

    required public init?(dictionary: [String:Any]) {

            id = dictionary["id"] as! Int
            bookName = dictionary["bookName"] as! String
        }

    public class func modelsFromArray(array:NSArray) -> [Book]
    {
        var models:[Book] = []
        for item in array
        {
            models.append(Book(dictionary: item as! [String:Any])!)
        }
        return models
    }
}


 class Page {

    public var id : Int = 0
    public var pageName : String = ""

    required public init?(dictionary: [String:Any]) {

            id = dictionary["id"] as! Int
            pageName = dictionary["pageName"] as! String
        }



   public class func modelsFromArray(array:NSArray) -> [Page]
   {
     var models:[Page] = []
     for item in array
     {
       models.append(Page(dictionary: item as! [String:Any])!)
     }
     return models
   }
}




class Result {

    public var status : String = ""
    public var message : String = ""
    public var payload : Array<Any> // is this correct Any or AnyObject ?

// here below i need help so that i can pass Class type and then use it 
        required public init?<T>(dictionary: [String:Any], type : T.Type) {

            status = dictionary["status"] as! String
            message = dictionary["message"] as! String
           if (dictionary["payload"] != nil) { payload = type.modelsFromArray(array:dictionary["payload"] as!  NSArray ) // this is compiler error (Type T has no member modelsFromArray). How can i do here so that every time i pass in Class type or any thing on which i can initialize this class object with proper payload object.
        }
}
```

here is how i want to use above Classes . Below is code example for getting Book end-point

```
let jsonResponse  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String:Any]

                            result = Result(dictionary: jsonResponse , Book.self // or Book or what?)!
```

I would appreciate if someone can guide me doing this in any other best way

Thanks :)

Comment: "or Book or what?"? - what?

Comment: Not related but why are all properties in `Book` and `Page` optional and why is the required initializer failable although all parameters are clearly non-optional. The initializer will never fail but it could crash.

Comment: @Abizern i mean to say how can i pass Book Type or what should i pass so that i can call Book class method over that

Comment: @vadian you are right. i have edited my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this way.

```
 if type == Book.self {
            if (dictionary["payload"] != nil) { payload = Book.modelsFromArray(array:dictionary["payload"] as!  NSArray )
            }
            } else {
                if (dictionary["payload"] != nil) { payload = Page.modelsFromArray(array:dictionary["payload"] as!  NSArray ) 
                }
            }
```

Comment: i will try that but i am getting compile time error on

`if (dictionary["payload"] != nil) { payload = type.modelsFromArray(array:dictionary["payload"] as!  NSArray )`


(Type T has no member modelsFromArray) . how can i do this part

Comment: I edited my answer, sorry for the confusion. Please let me know if this solution helps

Comment: that is good. Although this kills the generic approach as when there is new model, we have to add another if condition But this at least is a workaround